# What pattern should be used to validate 2 BIN MasterCard numbers

Tags: regex, validation, mastercard

"2" series BIN MasterCard numbers will start in October 2016.  What regex pattern should be used to validate them.  Today, we use the below pattern for MasterCards which start with 5:

```
var re = /^5[1-5]\d{2}-?\d{4}-?\d{4}-?\d{4}$/;
```

Comment: what are possibilities in these numbers?

Comment: I don't know why this question has been down voted.

Comment: This looks very clear to me.

Comment: Might help you. http://rgxg.sourceforge.net/

Comment: So would this. https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-common/pull/88/files#diff-96ff2b6b860cf039a754070984b61486R122

Comment: @dml do you have Sample Mastercard Numbers for the said range? If you have then please share.

Comment: The question is perfectly clear. Why was it closed???

Answer (score 16):

The answer by @Rawing incorrectly assumes that the BIN range of a MasterCard number will be changed to the new range while it is correct that the BIN range will be **extended** by the new range.

Therefore for future visitors that (blindly) copy the regex you should use this version to allow all "valid" MasterCard numbers (excluding luhn-check):

```
/^5[1-5]\d{2}-?\d{4}-?\d{4}-?\d{4}$|^2(?:2(?:2[1-9]|[3-9]\d)|[3-6]\d\d|7(?:[01]\d|20))-?\d{4}-?\d{4}-?\d{4}$/
```

Or this version without allowing dashes between the numbers:

```
/^5[1-5]\d{14}$|^2(?:2(?:2[1-9]|[3-9]\d)|[3-6]\d\d|7(?:[01]\d|20))\d{12}$/
```

This is basically a combination of @Rawings answer and the question.

*I know this does not strictly answer the question but will hopefully prevent some copy-paste bugs in payment forms.*

[Extended Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mH6fI1/2)

Comment: That was my first thought when I didn't see a "5" in the original answer. Thanks!

Comment: @migg : working (Y)
Can you please provide sample mastercard numbers for the said range i.e 2221-2720, I need it for testing?

Comment: The numbers in the extended demo match the regex but fail the checksum validation needed for credit card numbers. Link to a demo with valid credit card numbers: https://regex101.com/r/cGQNpd/3

Comment: And if anyone wants to handle randomly inserted spaces or dashes as it often happens in real production, use this: `(([5][\s-]*)([1-7][\s-]*)(\d[\s-]*){14})|2[\s-]*(?:2[\s-]*(?:2[\s-]*[1-9]|[3-9][\s-]*\d)|[3-6][\s-]*\d[\s-]*\d|7[\s-]*(?:[01][\s-]*\d|2[\s-]*0[\s-]*))(\d[\s-]*){12}`

Comment: Sarah Elan, you are refferring to the Luhn algorithm?